# What are the criteria to assess the complexity of parsing and from which parameters to issue the cost of work?

Tags: parsing, scrapy

I recently had an order to parse a price tag and find the best time to buy a product. Since then I've been interested in scrapy and other parsing libs and wanted to do some work, but I don't know how to evaluate myself (in money) and which orders will be harder than others...

Questions:

1.How to understand that parsing would be problematic enough?

2.How to evaluate (in money) problematic and simple sites \ tasks?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your requirements, you need to create a spider which scraps periodically and fetch price details of unique product from the required sites. also set up a margin price for each product and compare them effectively.

Use a database to save the details and handle offers or coupons separately to understand the price variation.

Comment: I meant that if I am given an order to parse the site (for example), how do I know that some tags will be difficult to scrape, how much will the whole parsing cost in the end...

Comment: Example # Here's one person who gave me the task to parse an online store with a  200 thousand goods. In each of them I need to collect pictures, price, description, name and color. Output the data to csv or json. After all, how am I supposed to know that ~40 hours of parsing will cost N dollars?

Comment: The thing you can do to find out the complexity of the site is, you should manually check the website HTML page. If the site does provide static or dynamic requests or Is there an API which returns product details etc

Comment: Check the website and understand the complexity to code, then fix the N dollars.

Comment: For example, if I was ordered to parse gearbest.com products (I think it's about 200 000 - 300,000) - just titles with price and pictures  , what is the price of this parsing (+-)?